# Error: Open failed: No such file or directory

Tags: android, storage

I am using a compression library to compress an image.

```
File croppedImagePath = new File(imageUri.getPath());

             try {
                 croppedBitmap = new Compressor(getActivity()).compressToBitmap(croppedImagePath);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

ERROR:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

When I locate the image this is the official file path

[image: Football Image]

I have confirmed I have READ and WRITE external storage permissions by adding them to the manifest as well as requesting permission in the activity.

I have tried getting the absolute file path by adding:

```
File absoluteCroppedImagePath = new File(croppedImagePath.getAbsolutePath());
```

But the file path doesn't change.

Comment: `File(imageUri.getPath());`. getPath() does not deliver a file system path. Hence you cannot use it with the File class.

Comment: `/document/image:25`. That is not a valid file system path as you might realise.

Comment: Have a look at imageUri.toString().

Comment: Using imageUri.toString() I get this error:
`/content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A25: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: `When I locate the image this is the official file path` ? Which app is telling you so?

Comment: You cannot use a content scheme with the File class either as a content scheme is no file system path.

Comment: The pre-installed Google photos app shows /documents/.. but Android Studio is giving me the /content:/ path